# How create a virtual dom of an existing HTML page?

Tags: javascript, virtualization, virtual-dom

How can I turn an existing DOM (existing HTML page) into a virtual DOM? I tried going through some libraries like [maquette](https://maquettejs.org/typedoc/index.html), [vdom-virtualize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vdom-virtualize), [virtual-dom](https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom), but did not understand how to approach this.

I want to monitor an HTML and whenever a mutation occurs, I want to patch the change using a virtual-dom. How could I do this? I have not found a clear way of doing this. The HTML that I want to monitor or create a virtual-dom of is a regular HTML code.

Could someone show a small example?

Comment: maybe you can reference some frameworks like vue? Forget which library inspires vue's virtual-dom conception

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/TimBeyer/html-to-vdom)? Used alongwith virtual-dom